# Where can I find MongoDB 2.0 documentation / manual

Tags: mongodb, documentation

I have MongoDB 2.0 version running in the production on some servers. I'm currently unable to upgrade them to 2.2 or 2.4 for various reasons, but I'm planning to do it in the future.

On mongodb.org there are only 2.2 and 2.4 versions of the documentation. Where can I find the 2.0 documentation?

Comment: Unfortunately I know of no mirror for older docs atm

Comment: Or maybe the docs repository: https://github.com/mongodb/docs

Comment: @WiredPrairie I've used archive.org but I was hoping there is some kind of archive for old docs on mongodb.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the documentation will state in which version things got introduced, so I would suggest to just use the 2.2 documentation and watch those statements.

Comment: I noticed that, but I don't think they are showing deprecated options. But I guess v.2.2 docs combined with archive.org will have to do.

Comment: Luckily we don't tend to deprecate a lot of stuff :-)